# Low Security Password/Username Concept Flask Security Error

Tags: python, flask, internal-server-error

Basically just trying to make a simple login page that has pretty much no security but keep getting internal server errors, any help with where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated. I've tried searching around but I can't find anything. I'm also pretty new to Python, so go easy :)

Python/Flask:

```
@app.route('/adminlogin')
def admin():
    return render_template('adminlogin.html')

@app.route('/adminDetails', methods =['POST'])  
    def adminLogin():
        correctUser = 'admin'
        correctPass = 'Password1'
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

    if username == correctUser & password == correctPass:
        adminSuccess()
    else: 
        admin()


@app.route('/admin')
def adminSuccess():
    return render_template('admin.html')
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/adminDetails" method="post">
        Username<input name="username" type = "text" maxlength="32" size="12" placeholder="Username" required><br>
        Password<input name ="password" type="password" maxlength="20" size="12" placeholder="Password" required><br>
        <button class ="menuitem" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        <button class="menuitem" type ="reset" value ="Clear">Clear</button>
    </form>
```

Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__ 
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1566, in make_response
        raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
    ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Comment: Please read the error messages. They presumably tell you that `Password1` is not defined, which it isn't. Where are you hoping for the value for that variable to come from?

Comment: From the form in the HTML?

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't comment, I have to leave this piece advice in the answer section. 
You should try running your app with debug set to true. This would give you the whole traceback of what caused the error instead of "Internal server error"

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Post the traceback and we'll all be in a better position to help you.

Edit: Your traceback says that your view function doesn't actually return anything. They need to return some kind of response. So what you need to do is return those function calls in your if else statements in your `adminLogin()` view

Comment: As of right now debug = True causes an error (errno 9).

Comment: Okay this might sound trivial but since you said you're new to Python I think it's worth mentioning `def adminLogin():` is unindented. I really hope this isn't it :p

Comment: I fixed python, the traceback ends with ValueError: View function did not return a response

Comment: Okay so I copy pasted your whole code locally and in order to make it run I fixed up a couple of things.
In your template change your submit button to input type.
`<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">`

and in your view change the `&` to `and`, as explained by the other answerer here, in Python `&` doesn't perform like you would think it would.  I hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh. In your if and else statements you need to put `return` before each function call. So like `return admin()` instead of just `admin()`

Comment: I wonder a simple return can solve the problem. We should redirect the page, right? Add a return will still on the `/adminDetails` route, not `/adminlogin` or `/admin` page. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
if username == admin & password == Password1:
```

it should be:

```
if username == admin and password == Password1:
```

---

For example:

```
>>> 1 == 1 & 2 == 2
False
```

And you may give us the full error log so that we can figure out the error.

---

The error log shows the reason:

> ValueError: View function did not return a response

so you need to redirect to the page.

```
@app.route('/adminDetails', methods =['POST'])  
def adminLogin():
    correctUser = 'admin'
    correctPass = 'Password1'
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    if username == correctUser and password == correctPass:
        return redirect(url_for('adminSuccess'))
    else: 
        return redirect(url_for('admin'))
```

Documentation: [redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors)

Comment: I don't get any errors, I just get an internal server error in the browser.

Comment: Use debug mode and it should give you the full backtrace.

Comment: I've posted the full traceback now